# Self Congratulation

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a positive connotation of self-congratulations. It's a part of a write-up where I wanna emphasize that we should take pat ourselves on the back for our achievements and acknowledge our hard work and sincerity. The best phrase that comes to mind is the title of this question however it clearly has a boastful and complacent ring to it. I am looking for something more deserving and appreciative. Hope this is the right stack-exchange website for this.

Comment: "Our team has done an excellent job this quarter and has solved a lot of tough problems. [name] did some especially hard work on [thing], and [name] helped me a lot personally with [other thing]..."

Comment: yes @Sciborg, what is this objective analytic view of good outcomes being attributed to steady work called?

Comment: Oh, I apologize - you were looking for a word! I misunderstood the question. I think some appropriate words could just be "appreciation" or "acknowledgment."

Comment: This might be off-topic here, but over on https://english.stackexchange.com/ they even have a _tag_ for single-word-requests. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Learning to love yourself first:***

I'm just going to throw out what I think you're trying to get to. Hopefully it helps.

- Self-esteem?
- Satisfaction?
- Vindication?
- Achievement?
- Self-assurance/self-assured?
- Justified/justification?
- Self-confident?